# How do I remove nested folder in the root of my repo in Visual Studio TFS Git?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am using Microsoft's Visual Studio TFS Thingamabob Cloud Service (I don't know what it's called because Microsoft's product and service nomenclature is bewildering). I created a repo on the server and then committed and pushed my changes. Here's what I got under the code section of the site:

```
 My Code
    My Code
       my files
       my files ...
```

How do I move "my files" to the root "My Code" which is the root of the repo, i.e. remove the redundant "My Code" folder?   Who told Microsoft to put my folder there?  Where's the root of my source folder?

Comment: Wow! No answers.  If it's easy, then you expect someone to answer and get some points. Man, software has gone down the tubes forever. We'll never see the macintosh again.